# Setting cron for indexing

Tags: php, search, cron

This is not any specific coding problems. I wanted `theoretical` knowledge and views/comments of the following: (or please post a link to some blog that you may direct me to!)

I'm trying to develop a search facility for one of my projects. Basically, the search will be able to return almost everything in the database. For this, I thought of indexing through the cron.

I'm just a newbie. I wanted to know what are the different things I will need to take care about in the indexing for cron? Apart from `memory size required`, `time interval of successive crons` and `updating from the last cron run`.

I'm using `PHP`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that your indexed tables are carrying last updated fields which most databases now provide. Your indexing script should be designed, keeping in mind incremental updates to the index. Assuming you have decided to choose Solr(or Lucene directly) you would have to reopen the index every time the update cron script executes and then add/update the search records based on database changes. I would recommend making an index copy and then updating and using some automated test queries to ensure operations to be functional and then move that to the live copy. Its best to use Solr rather than Zend Lucene as it is very hard to scale with the latter. Solr running as a server gives you a lot of options to cache and optimize search queries which I have not seen in Zend Lucene.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Solr only.